# 2 background-image на select

Tags: html, css, select, html-select

подскажите как вставить 2 иконки как здесь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
select{
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-content: center;
 background-color: #f1f5fa;
 appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 98% center;
 background-size: 10px;
 background-image: url(https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Arrows/expand_arrow1600.png);
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: $input;
    font-size: 14px;
}

select{
  border: 1px solid #e7ecfa;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-position: calc(100% - 10px) center;
  position: relative;
  &:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px;
    background-position: left center;
    background-image: url(https://c7.uihere.com/files/372/517/156/computer-icons-real-time-computing-timer.jpg);
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">2 дня</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Используйте пожалуйста css в примере кода, ибо у вас scss. Так же много лишних стилей. Я не стал редактировать ваш код, а просто добавил решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
select {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #f1f5fa;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2% center, 98% center;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://c7.uihere.com/files/372/517/156/computer-icons-real-time-computing-timer.jpg), url(https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Arrows/expand_arrow1600.png);
  border: 0;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid #e7ecfa;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">2 дня</option>
</select>
```